# Dolphin - no files visible - "file protocol died" - howto resurrect

Tags: dolphin

There it is, once more:

```
The process for the file protocol died unexpectedly
```

in red! Dolphin doesn't show files, except of the current directory before the death. Closing every instance and restarting doesn't help. Starting from command-line shows:

```
QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
```

when the error is displayed. And when clicking on some favorites:

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database" 
QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
```

It works for ssh-fs links (fish as protocol)... thats suprising.

I hope it's not related to the nfs directories... but that would help: what is the reason for this crash? Is it possible without reboot / logout and -in to get dolphin running again?

Nautilus works fine, mc also. I'm running Debian Jessie (Testing) with Gnome 3. (And I don't like nautilus :)

Comment: Hmm... got this out the blue with "Trying to convert empty KLocalizedString to QString. Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  PlacesView(0xBLAH)  index:  28 The process for the trash protocol died unexpectedly." Sounds like KDE levels of stable.

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me in awesomewm after updating some KDE packages.  When launching dolphin from a terminal, I got:

```
kf5.kio.core: "The process for the tags protocol died unexpectedly."
kf5.kio.core: "The process for the trash protocol died unexpectedly."
```

and nothing was visible in Dolphin (other than the same red error message as OP).

The solution seemed to be killing `kdeinit5`.

Comment: Is killing a process really a solution? Is this something that you needed to do just the once after the upgrade, or something you need to keep doing to allow KDE to work properly?

Comment: I agree, it's not a "solution" in that it doesn't identify/fix whatever the actual bug was.  But it's better than restarting your computer, which is all I found for advice elsewhere.  And no, I've used Dolphin (outside of KDE) for probably 10 years and only needed to do this once.

Comment: Whoa, three years later and the same solution just worked for me - no matter that I've rebooted countless times in the meantime, or the fact that I've upgraded lots of packages on my system, killing kdeinit5 fixed it. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Well....it might be time to restore the database files from backups, presuming you do periodically make them.

A couple of other thought include package corruption, you could reinstall the old package over the current one.

Second, what about a compromised server?

Comment: um... no... what? I need to say, this problem happened already some time ago and it was gone for some weeks. So no broken database, which needs to be restored... Since it's a local problem, no compromise needs to be assumed.